# Can't use random within a function Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am working on a bot for discord and I  need to have a new randomly generated number each time the function is called. How can I do so? I tried this but it doesn't work, I just get an error saying "object has no attribute 'randint'"

```
@bot.command()
async def test(*, message: str=None):
    if message is None:
        r = random.randint(0, 6779)
        await bot.say(r)
```

Comment: What is "doesn't work"? What's the current/expected behavior?

Comment: ... Ok. What's your `random` object? How did you `import random`? Is there any other usage of `random` in your code? [mcve] please.

Comment: I imported random as I have in the past: "import random". I haven't used any random anywhere else.

Comment: [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [mcve] please .

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
random.choice(range(0,6779))
```

instead of

```
random.randint(0, 6779)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is where you have written

```py
random.randint(0, 6779)
```

you should write

```py
random.choice(range(0,6779))
```

instead of that